# I need to join four dataset results into one tablix

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have four datasets that get information for four different things (a unique set of fields for each one), but that can be joined using a field they share.  I need to get them all into a tablix that will have four rows, one for each dataset per the linking field.  How do I do that?

Currently I can only put in values from one dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the best idea would be to create a query that joins the datasets in the sql. If that is not possible, you can look into using the [Lookup function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) to find info from other datasets in your report. The related [Lookupset function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819.aspx) is able to retrieve sets of information and may be useful as well.

Comment: Looking around at other similar questions, it seems as this is the way to go.  I think I'll go with the lookup function, but I appreciate the answer/options!